# Characteristics of Wildfire - GoT

Tags: game-of-thrones

I would like to know, what are the characteristics of "[Wildfire](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wildfire)" (as opposed to normal fire) in the Game of Thrones TV Series?

[image: Wildfire]

Comment: Never heard of Valyrian Fire. In what context did you hear this?

Comment: If your referring to the game of thrones then Valyrian fire is not really explained beyond its magically enhanced somehow, it may also burn much hotter allowing the steel to be alloyed with better metals which in turn make a better blade

Comment: Do you mean wildfire or perhaps dragon fire?

Comment: Oh, is this a case of some people watching the TV-show without subtitles and thinking they hear "valyrian fire" instead of "wildfire"?

Comment: You might be thinking of 'valyrian steel' or 'wildfire'. As far as I am aware, there is no such thing as 'valyrian fire'.

Comment: Sorry guys, I watched the spanish subtitles and it mentioned, "Fuego Varyo" , that means Valyrian Fire, I didnt think could be a translation mistake.

Comment: You'll have to tell us where and how its mentioned then.

Comment: Before Stannis attacked King's Landing, an alchemist shows to Tyrion the pots with a kind of liquid that makes the Fire.

Comment: Also , I think somebody mentioned (I dont remember when), that Lianna Stark was burned with this kind of fire.

Comment: @JeanPaul - You're referring to wildfire; http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wildfire The Spanish version may translate it differently...

Comment: @JeanPaul Lyanna Stark did not die to wildfire, but her father lord Rickard Stark was roasted by the mad king Aerys using wildfire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Temperature

According to the TV Series, burning wilfire is capable of melting the following substances;

> "The Substance burns so hot it melts **wood**, **stone**... even **steel**... and,
>   of course, flesh!. The Substance burns so hot it melts **flesh**... like
>   tallow."

Assuming the maester is correct, it will burn hot enough to melt [steel](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/melting-temperature-metals-d_860.html) (at approx 1500°C) and [stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granite) (at approx 1200°C). Although they explicitly mention melting wood, the reality is that the temperature required to achieve such a [feat](http://www.yalescientific.org/2010/05/everyday-qa-can-you-melt-a-wooden-log/) (approx 3500°C) strongly suggests that this is mere hyperbole.

### Composition

From the same canon source, we also know that it combusts readily in the presence of urine and burns with a green flame.

While there are a variety of elements that burn with a green flame (including copper, antimony, selenium, tellurium, thallium and barium) the only one of these elements that would readily react with the water in urine is Barium which would cause steam, heat and highly combustible hydrogen gas, potentially leading to an explosion.

### Appearance

[image: Wildfire Liquid]

Wildfire is stored as a greenish transparent liquid. According to Bronn it's highly combustible and can explode from merely being handled ungently.

### Out of Universe

The wildfire that was used to coat Baris' 'Flaming sword' is [composed of](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/2012/12/6/prop-closeup-berics-flaming-sword.html) "Isopropyl Alcohol" and kept alight with "a small pilot light". The flame was artificially coloured using CGI effects by Pixomondo, who won an Effects Emmy for the series.

According to various fan sites, the liquid version is allegedly distilled water mixed with glycol and green food colouring although I've been unable to locate a canon confirmation.

If you're after more of an historical perspective, there is an extensive reference on the subject of wildfire on the [GoT Wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wildfire)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, its clear now.

Comment: I assume that "melting wood" is something only achievable in a lab, as wood will catch fire in the presence of oxygen and high temperature.

Comment: @TLP2 - Yes, you need to heat it under pressure to stop it from just burning

Answer (score 1):

Since it's apparent that you're talking about the substance known as wildfire in the English originals, it's almost certainly based on [Greek fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire), a Byzantine naval weapon whose formula has been lost, and so we can only speculate on what exactly it was.

Comment: In Greek, it's called 'Υγρό Πυρ'